# Android cannot run

Tags: android, eclipse

This is my first time of using android (am a complete newbie)

Have been trying to run the my hello world application (presumably the simplest stuff on android)

When i click run, it shows me this:

```
[2011-05-31 01:28:55 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-05-31 01:28:55 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-05-31 01:28:55 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.bestvalue.hello.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-05-31 01:28:55 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2011-05-31 01:28:55 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2011-05-31 01:29:00 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-05-31 01:29:00 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

and there we are for ages showing me a black clear screen and absolutely nothing else.

I dont know if its my system speed (but i run a 4gb , 2.0 ghz dual amd system)

Please what do i do from here to enable me continue?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

after a long wait, it added this line:

```
[2011-05-31 02:00:37 - HelloAndroid] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.bestvalue.hello.HelloAndroid activity launch'!
```

**UPDATE**

It got to this point before terminating now

```
[2011-05-31 09:10:49 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2011-05-31 09:10:49 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-05-31 09:10:49 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-05-31 09:10:49 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.bestvalue.hello.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-05-31 09:10:49 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2011-05-31 09:10:56 - HelloAndroid] Launch canceled!
```

**UPDATE:**

When i run it brings out the Android Device Chooser. Under choosing a running android device, it shows emulator 5444 and the under target i have a ?. is there something i still need to setup?

Comment: Never mind deploying and running an app, are you able to successfully start and use an emulator instance?

Comment: I've never gotten my app to run in the emulator.  I do all testing on a real phone.  They're cheap, right?

Comment: @Programmer Bruce, pls i dnt really understand . @jeffamaphone, dont have an android phone now (hoping to get soon), but in the mean time am looking at work i can work with

Comment: Follow links in the first step in the dev guide at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/index.html for instructions on managing AVDs.  Running an emulator is covered at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html.

Comment: that is compatibility problem with your app and target device double check that...

Answer (score 0):

That happens to me too sometimes. The trick is this, press the Eclipse 'Run' button once and the Emulator comes up. Once you can see the android Home Screen/Desktop then press the 'Run' button in Eclipse again.

Now you app should actually start up. I think that the reason it does this is that the intent times out because the emulator takes too long to start up. (That is just a wild guess though; all I know is that pressing the 'Run' button again when the emulator is up just works.)

Comment: @Robert Massaioli , i tried your suggestion. i am still stuck. please kindly refer to my update. thanks

Comment: @Ogugua: What API level are you trying to develop for and have you actually created a device image yet (like the instructions in this link say http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html#createavd)?

Comment: @Robert Massaioli , api 12; yes i think i have created an avd

Comment: Well if you set the target for the app in the Eclipse preferences and in the Android Manifest and there is a Honeycomb AVD sitting there waiting for you to start then I do not know what the problem is.

Comment: doesnt seem as if i have set the target in the preferences and manifest. I am under preferences now, the sdk location path is it to the android folder or the android/android-sdk folder or the android/android-sdk/tools folders? how can i set it in the manifest. thanks

Comment: I searched google for "android set target manifest" and got this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html which is what you should use.

Comment: @Robert Massaioli , i also noticed that each time i open eclipse, the adt installation clears and i have to install again. is there anything i can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I just fixed it. According to my way, go to the *Run Configuration* and in the Android configuration part, press the "browse" button, select the project you created and everything's ok then. Works for me. Good luck man.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the phone. If restarting eclipse or Windows is not enough.